# Using regex to find/replace in PhpStorm

Tags: regex, replace, phpstorm

I am working to refactor a dependency on Compass mixins to simply use CSS rules which will be vendor prefixed by autoprefixer as a post process.

So I am going through a large code-base with the need to replace strings such as:

```
@include border-radius($big-radius);
```

With something like:

```
border-radius: $big-radius;
```

The IDE I am using is PhpStorm, which provides a find/replace regex feature. What should the regex for the case above look like? I'm sure I can adapt that for many other purposes as I continue working on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Search for:

```
@include (.*)\((.*)\);
```

Replace with:

```
$1: $2;
```

The `(.*)` parts creates groups. the `$<number>` reference those groups.

Comment: Don't forget the ; or remove it from the first search